# Backup HFS+ drive on Windows machine

Tags: windows, macos, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I'm imaging a hard drive that has a copy of OSX (10.8 I believe) installed on it and is beginning to fail. I need to backup the entire Macintosh HD partition to a network drive, from a Windows machine. Any suggestions for what backup and restore program I should use to image this drive?

Comment: does it have to be running windows at the time? You could boot from a linux livecd, and since its beginning to fail, use a recovery centric backup software like gddrescue.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Make that an Answer. If you use a tool like ddrescue to copy a disk block-for-block to a file, you can just append ".dmg" to the file name and Mac OS X's Disk Utility will treat it as a disk image, making it easy to use Disk Utility to restore it onto another disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows dosen't really have the fun disk imaging tools - I'd boot into a linux livecd (I prefer ubuntu), install the gnu ddrescue (not to be confused with the other sort), and use that to image the drive.

ddrescue should handle any errors it comes across, recover as much as it can on a first pass, and then try again for the stuff it missed. This is a pretty good stratergy for drive recovery and it handles bad blocks gracefully.

Since linux has some hfs+ support you should also be able to mount the imaged drive with kpartx in linux for quick file recoveries, or just peek at the drive you're imaging (once you're done, hopefully)

While you can't stream the image directly to a network location using pipes like you would with dd, this should work with a network drive as a destination (though, I'd recommend a local HDD for speed's sake), and according to the comments, Disk utility will treat a .dmg extentioned sparse image as a regular backup and let you restore it.

Answer (score 1):

[Paragon HFS for Windows](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/hfs-windows/) (commercial) is able to read/write to HFS disks in Windows

Update. Apple Boot Camp drives also include a free ready-only driver for Windows. But i'm not sure if one is able to install them on non-bootcamp windows (running on apple hardware).

Comment: I was using a Mac machine, with Windows installed on one partition. I had the BootCamp driver packages from Apple, but it wasn't technically a "BootCamp machine." Don't think it really matters though.